# Sencha: set image as background to a panel

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, panel, background-image

I want to set a background image in sencha to a panel:

**EDIT**

```
Ext.define('components.NewPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
style: {
    background:'#ffffff',
    backgroundImage: 'url(icon.PNG)',
    backgroundSize: '10% 85%',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundPosition: 'bottom left',
},

initialize: function () {

    var newIcon=Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
        src: "image1.png",
        cls: "img",
        scope: this,
        listeners: {
                    tap: {
                        fn :function (img, evt) {
                            Ext.Msg.alert("This is a test");
                        },// function
                    }// tap
        }//listeners
    });//create
    this.add([newIcon]);
},
config: {
    layout: {
        type: 'fit'
    }
}

});
```

But nothing is displayed. What to do? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're referencing the correct location in the `url()`?

Comment: yes, the correct location is referred in the url()

Comment: Try setting only a `background-color`. It could be that your Panel isn't correctly initiated, or its height / width is 0. `#ff00ff` is a useful debugging colour ;-)

Comment: Then the issue isn't with the CSS declaration for the background image, but rather the dimensions of your panel, or the CSS declarations in their entirety. Do you have a link that we can look over, as it will be much easier to debug.

Comment: I will show my code. My question is edited, my code is entirely showed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as bellow

```
   Ext.define('MyApp.view.WelcomePanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.WelcomePanel',

    config: {
        style:"background-color:white;",
        itemId:'WelcomePanel',
        fullscreen:true,
        layout: 'card',
        html:'<div align="center" style="background-color:white;" ><img src="http://src.sencha.io/http://yoursite.com/splash.png" ></div>',
        items: [
                {xtype:'MainPanel', docked:'top'},

        ]
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to set the background of the panel body to transparent, because otherwise that white background prevented my image from showing. Try adding this:

```
bodyStyle: 'background: transparent;',
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `bodyStyle` config

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        border: false,
        bodyStyle: {
        'background': 'url(wall.jpg) !important'
         }
        //another config
        ....
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this @b.i and here we go!,

```
var panel = new Ext.Panel({
    id:'pnl1',
    fullscreen:true,
    style: {
        background:'#ffffff',
        backgroundImage: 'url(path/image/your_image.PNG)',
        backgroundSize: '100% 100%',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        backgroundPosition: 'bottom left',
    },
    html: '<img class="logo" src="path/image/another_image_yours.jpg"/>',
    layout: {
        type:'card',
    },
    items:[]
})
```

Create this panel and after can you use it. Try create single and view your image first.

`backgroundSize: x y` is size of your image and `backgroundPosition: x y` is position of your image.

I hope help you. :) Ciao

Comment: I am putting the style: {
    background:'#ffffff',
    backgroundImage: 'url(path/image/your_image.PNG)',
    backgroundSize: '10% 85%',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundPosition: 'bottom left',
} at a wrong place?

Comment: I update my answer @b.i Anything let me know or accept this answer :)